# Docker /bin bindings into containers

Tags: docker

I'm running in a closed environment on a hardened RHEL 7.2 server. The System team hardened this server and it appears I cannot run `chown` in my user context, I get `Operation not permitted`.

For some reason, when I try to run a docker container that uses `chown` in its docker entry point bash file, I get the same error message. Looks like the container is using the host's `/bin/chown` to run stuff inside the container and fails to do so due to the hardening.

If I copy `/bin/chown` into `$HOME/.local/bin/chown` I can run it correctly, is there a way to tell docker to use my local chown instead of `/bin/chown`?

Comment: Just add `$HOME/.local/bin/chown` to your `PATH` environment variable. `echo 'export PATH=$HOME/.local/bin/chown:$PATH' >> ~/.bashrc`.

Comment: @Thomas tried that, still seeing the same result. I also made sure that the `.local/bin` part is before the default `$PATH`. Getting the same error message. I also tried to run the container with `-v /home/user/.local/bin/chown:/bin/chown` and still getting the same message.